# Behavior of ECHO Command and Variable Usage in Unix

Tags: unix, echo

Can't post the image directly yet, so here's a link to it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOfIv.png

I'm trying to learn some basic unix file scripting for an Informatica project I'm working on. I've used a few scripts in the past and have only a very rudimentary idea of what to do so I'm just playing around with the various parts of an existing script.

I can't make heads or tails of some of the behavior of the commands. Here is an example using ECHO. The thing appears to just randomly return one of: the variable I defined, the variable name, or an error.

e.g. why does:
`$ _Src="/home/axxxxxx"`
`$ echo "${_Src}"`

return
`/home/axxxxxx`

but
`$ INFA_HOME="/home"`
`$ echo "${INFA_HOME}"`

returns
`ksh: "${INFA_HOME_^H}": bad substitution`

other inscrutable behavior:
`$ echo "${INFA_HOME} now"`
`>`
`$ echo "${INFA_HOME} now"`
`/home now`
`$ echo "${INFA_HOME} "`
`{INFA_HOME}`
`$ echo "${INFA_HOME} now"`
`/home now`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your terminal has some issues. Make sure `echo $TERM` agrees with the emulation mode of the terminal, and that locales etc. are correctly set up.

Comment: This is not terminal issue its the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your putty or terminal settings. You may see in the image below the string works as expected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CQ1j.png

the screenshot that you shared shows "^H" which is equivalent to backspace, so the chances you might have used that. The next time you use the variable it prints the output as expected.
Even with the first variable all goes fine.